# Listar array con post en php

Tags: php, array

estoy intentando hacer que el resultado de un formulario se interprete con una lista de un array.

Tengo este formulario en "formuilario.php:

```
    <form action="contenido.php" method="post">
    Nombre: <input type="text" name="nombre"><br><br>
    E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br><br>
    Valoración: <br><br>
<?php
    $valoracion = array("Muy mala", "Mala", "Media", "Buena", "Muy buena");
?>
    <label for="$valoracion[4]">Muy buena</label>
    <input type="radio" id="$valoracion[4]" name="valoracion" value="$valoracion[4]" checked><br>
    <label for="$valoracion[3]">Buena</label>
    <input type="radio" id="$valoracion[3]" name="valoracion" value="$valoracion[3]"><br>
    <label for="$valoracion[2]">Media</label>
    <input type="radio" id="$valoracion[2]" name="valoracion" value="$valoracion[2]"><br>
    <label for="$valoracion[1]">Mala</label>
    <input type="radio" id="$valoracion[1]" name="valoracion" value="$valoracion[1]"><br>
    <label for="$valoracion[0]">Muy mala</label>
    <input type="radio" id="$valoracion[0]" name="valoracion" value="$valoracion[0]"><br><br>
          
    <input type="submit" name="enviar" value="Enviar">

</form>
```

Y este en contenido.php:

```
    <p>Formulario:</p><br />
    <?php
    echo nl2br("Nombre: ".$_POST['nombre']."<br />\n");
    echo nl2br("Email: ".$_POST['email']."<br />\n");
    $valoracion = array("Muy mala", "Mala", "Media", "Buena", "Muy buena");
    echo "Valoracion: ".$_POST['valoracion']."<br />\n";
    ?>
```

Lo que quería es que el resultado de valoración se interprete en base al array, pero me imprime valoracion[4] en vez de Muy buena.

Answer (score 1):

Tu problema es que cierras el bloque PHP antes de colocar los elementos del `form` y al hacer eso no te reconocerá la variable `$valoracion`.

```
<?php
    $valoracion = array("Muy mala", "Mala", "Media", "Buena", "Muy buena");
?> <!-- Aquí cierras bloque PHP y entras en bloque HTML --> 

    <!-- En este bloque (HTML) las variables PHP no son reconocidas -->
    <label for="$valoracion[4]">Muy buena</label>
```

Para resolverlo, mete todo dentro de un mismo bloque PHP y punto. Puedes hacer `echo` del `form`, **escapando las comillas dobles**.

La mezcla de bloques lleva a confusiones como la que te ocurren aquí.

```
<?php

    #Trasladamos la declaración del array al inicio
    $valoracion = array("Muy mala", "Mala", "Media", "Buena", "Muy buena");
    echo "
        <form action=\"contenido.php\" method=\"post\">
        Nombre: <input type=\"text\" name=\"nombre\"><br><br>
        E-mail: <input type=\"text\" name=\"email\"><br><br>
        Valoración: <br><br>
        <label for=\"$valoracion[4]\">Muy buena</label>
        <input type=\"radio\" id=\"$valoracion[4]\" name=\"valoracion\" value=\"$valoracion[4]\" checked><br>
        <label for=\"$valoracion[3]\">Buena</label>
        <input type=\"radio\" id=\"$valoracion[3]\" name=\"valoracion\" value=\"$valoracion[3]\"><br>
        <label for=\"$valoracion[2]\">Media</label>
        <input type=\"radio\" id=\"$valoracion[2]\" name=\"valoracion\" value=\"$valoracion[2]\"><br>
        <label for=\"$valoracion[1]\">Mala</label>
        <input type=\"radio\" id=\"$valoracion[1]\" name=\"valoracion\" value=\"$valoracion[1]\"><br>
        <label for=\"$valoracion[0]\">Muy mala</label>
        <input type=\"radio\" id=\"$valoracion[0]\" name=\"valoracion\" value=\"$valoracion[0]\"><br><br>
        <input type=\"submit\" name=\"enviar\" value=\"Enviar\">
    </form>";
```

Otra cosa que puedes hacer, ya que tienes el array, es usarlo para construir los `label` y los `radio` del formulario, creando un código más limpio y más portable:

```
<?php

    #OJO he reorganizado el orden del array
    $valoracion = array("Muy buena","Buena","Media","Mala","Muy mala");
    $form='<form action="contenido.php" method="post">
    Nombre: <input type="text" name="nombre"><br><br>
    E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br><br>
    Valoración: <br><br>';
    foreach ($valoracion as $k=>$v) {
        $form.=sprintf('<label for="%s">%s</label>',$v,$v);
        $checked=($k===0) ? "checked" : "";
        $form.=sprintf('<input type="radio" id="radio%d" name="valoracion" value="%s" %s><br>',$k,$v,$checked);
    }
    $form.='<input type="submit" name="enviar" value="Enviar">';
    $form.='</form>';
    echo $form;
```

En cuanto a la recepción de los datos en `contenido.php`, convendría que no te expongas a situaciones de *`Undefined index`*.

Para evitarlo, si todos los campos del `form` son obligatorios, puedes hacer algo así:

```
$nombre=$_POST['nombre'] ?? NULL;
$email=$_POST['email'] ?? NULL;
$radio=$_POST['valoracion'] ?? NULL;
if( isset($nombre) && isset($email) && isset($radio) ) {
    echo nl2br("Nombre: $nombre<br />\n");
    echo nl2br("Email: $email<br />\n");
    echo "Valoracion: $radio<br />\n";
    echo '<hr />';
}else{
    echo "Faltan datos en el POST";
}
```

Si algún dato es no obgligatorio, simplemente cambia el `NULL` por un dato en blanco, algo así:

```
$email=$_POST['email'] ?? "";
```

De este modo, pasará la verificación y te mostrará en blanco la parte del email.

Comment: Genial, gracias. Intentaba ponerlo dentro del PHP pero me daba error, porque no se podia meter un formulario dentro de un PHP. Intentaba que enviase la variable como un texto al "contenido.php" y que lo interpretase pero solo me lo mostraba como texto, supongo que no se puede hacer eso.

Comment: @Sesepote no entendí bien tu comentario. En realidad se puede hacer todo, pero hay que hacerlo de forma correcta. ¿Qué es lo que piensas que no se puede hacer?